# A nice gui terminal with splits for mac?

Tags: macos, terminal-emulator, terminal-multiplexer

Back in my Linux days with server, I had a complicated set up with a tmux session shared between windows.  I'm not doing this sort of work at the moment (less sysadmin, less log trawling, less servers) and am using a mac... but I'm starting to get a little bored by finding the "right" terminal window.

Is there a nice way to "group" a pane of terminals on mac without going all "tiling window managers? Are there any terminal emulators for mac that support horizontal and vertical splitting? On Linux I think terminator does this, but it [doesn't seem to work on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108560/install-terminator-on-macbook-as-terminal-emulator).

Comment: Did you try iTerm2?

Comment: Yes, just found this. The only issue I have is that I want to make option behave like alt and I don't seem to be able to do this globally.

Comment: Have you look at Termius, I think if fits what you are looking for.